# Hiding links on browser's statusbar when you mouseover on links for modals

Tags: javascript, mouseover, statusbar

I'm trying to disable the mouse over highlight in the statues bar. I have written this piece of JS code. It work fine. But the problem is with Bootstrap 3 Modals they are broken and not working how should i modify the code ? any ideas ?

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
          setTimeout(function () {
               
                $('a[href]').each(function () {
                    var href = this.href;
    
                    $(this).removeAttr('href').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function () {
                        if (href.toLowerCase().indexOf("#") >= 0) {
    
                        } else {
                         window.location.href = href;
                        }
                    });
                });
    
          }, 500);
    });
```

Thanks you,

Comment: _“I'm trying to disable the mouse over highlight in the statues bar.”_ - why? What are you hoping to actually achieve by this?

Comment: i want to hide the HREF link that shows in the status bar when i user hovers the mouse on any link on my site.

Comment: I didn’t ask for a repetition of what you already said, I asked _why_ you would want this. Why are users not supposed to see what your links point to?

Comment: im using codeigniter for my web app project. i want to hide controller, function and the segment names. im aware of the routing class bu some parts of my app clashes with the routes.

Comment: _“i want to hide controller, function and the segment names”_ - but _WHY_? How exactly is the world going to end, if the user where to see those?

Comment: im hiding my app in a frame. and the navigation working without the changing of the address bar link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221143/discussion-between-mumin-gazi-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```css
a[href] {
  cursor: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Using the inspect menu, see the styles that are applied by bootstrap and overwrite them using your own CSS with !important tags